# Should I use Sum method and Count/Length find the element of array that is the closest to the middle value of all elements?

Tags: c#, arrays, count, sum, average

If I have `arr=[1,3,4,-7,9,11]`, the average value is **(1+3+4-7+9+11) /6 = 3.5**, then elements 3 and 4 are equally distant to 3.5, but smaller of them is 3 so 3 is the result.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I have found an average in array {1,3,4,-7,9,11}, which is 3.5, but i am not sure how to get smaller element which is closest to average 3.5, which is 3? I know that i need to use another iteration. I am relatively new, so my question might seem simplistic to most of you guys.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking the best approach to find the value in the array closest to the mean of the values in the array, and if two values are equally close then to pick the value that's the lesser of the two value?

Comment: Scan the array, try each item while tracking the best so far

Comment: Yeah, i am asking the best approach to find the value in the array which is closest to the mean of the values in array

Comment: You mean like this? `var result = arr.OrderByDescending(a => a).Where(a => a <= meanValue).First()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have worked out the average (`avg` below) then you can get the diff for each item, then order by the diff, and get the first item. This will give you the *closest* item in the array

```
var nearestDiff = arr.Select(x => new { Value=x, Diff = Math.Abs(avg-x)})
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Diff)
                     .First().Value;
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iKvmhp

If instead you must get the item lower than the average

```
var lowerDiff = arr.Where(x => x<avg)
                      .OrderByDescending(x =>x)
                      .First();
```

You'll need `using System.Linq` for either of the above to work

Comment: Note that for .net 5 (and maybe .net Core 3.1) this solution does NOT have to do a complete sort. There's an optimisation for `.OrderBy().First()` which makes the complexity of this solution `O(N)` rather than `O(N.Log(N))` (In case anyone objects to the sort!)

Comment: I think you're missing the tie-breaker to pick the lowest value if two values are equally distant from the average.

Comment: @Xerillio well you'll only get 1 result so there clearly is a tiebreaker. It might be the _wrong_ tie breaker as it wont necessarily be the one lower than the average - my answer gets the closest to the average.

Comment: @Jamiec but the OP specifically states (albeit not very detailed) that the lowest value should be picked in case of ties, so this answer doesn't seem to fulfill that requirement

Comment: @Xerillio indeed, which is why im updating it!

Comment: Sorry, the edit addition doesn't work, same problem that I commented on the deleted answer from Mureinik. Plug in array `1,3,5` for example. You need to do `<= avg` or copy my comment above :)

Comment: Actually, even my comment doesn't work ha!

Comment: But if you add `.ThenBy(x => x.Value)` to your first block, it will choose the lower value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the average is first. That involves a cycle either implemented explicitly, or invoked implicitly. So, let's assume that you already know what the average value is, because your question refers to the way some values related to the average can be obtained. Let's implement a comparison function:

```
protected bool isBetter(double a, double b, double avg) {
    double absA = Abs(a - avg);
    double absB = Abs(b - avg);
    if (absA < absB) return a;
    else if (absA > absB) return b;
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

And now you can iterate your array, always compare via `isBetter` the current value with the best so far and if it's better, then it will be the new best. Whatever number ended up to be the best will be the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using GroupBy is a good way to do it

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 4, 3, -7, 9, 11 };
var avg = arr.Average();
var result = arr.GroupBy(x=>Math.Abs(avg-x)).OrderBy(g=>g.Key).First().OrderBy(x=>x).First();
```

Original Array

> [1,4,3,-7,9,11]

After grouping, key is abs distance from average, items are grouped according to that

> [2.5, [1]]
>
> [0.5, [4, 3]]
>
> [5.5, [9]]
>
> [7.5, [11]]
>
> [10.5, [-7]]

Order by group keys

> [0.5, [4, 3]]
>
> [2.5, [1]]
>
> [5.5, [9]]
>
> [7.5, [11]]
>
> [10.5, [-7]]

Take first group

> [4, 3]

Order group items

> [3, 4]

Take first item

> 3

*changed array to `[1,4,3,-7,9,11]`, reversing order of 3 and 4 because they are naturally ordered according to the output originally, and this is necessary to prove the last step*